# node-v not showing me the current version of node installed on my system

Tags: node.js

I recently installed nodejs on my system, did the environmental variable setup but still when i type node-v in cmd it keeps opening the node application not displaying the current version of node installed on my system.
Please what can be wrong?

Comment: Don't forget the space. It's `node -v`. You can also use `node --version` (note the double dash).

Answer (score 0):

To manage Node versions you can use [NVM](http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html):

```
nvm install 4
nvm use 4
```

[Another resource](https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b)

Comment: Thanks. I got to realize that after setting the environment variable and adding the path for the nodejs i did'nt restart my PC. so did the whole process all over again and did a Restart and it works fine now.